# Mount permanent drive in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Is it possible to mount a drive in powershell permanently? Even after system restart?

When I use `New-PSDrive -Persist` (and all other required parameters of course), it works only for the current windows session. I use PS 5.1

I can see the drive in file explorer, it is persistent in the system, but I don't see it from Powershell ISE, even if run by administrator. I have to use `New-PSDrive` to be able to load a script from a network drive, when I need to work on it. And whenever I reboot the computer, the drive once again can't be seen from the ISE. It's kind of annoying having to do it again and again all the time.

Comment: `net use` will work

Comment: @4c74356b41 `New-PSDrive` is the PowerShell equivalent to `net use`

Comment: So are you running the ISE as a different user?  Do you see the drive from `Get-PSDrive`?

Comment: No, I'm running the ISE as elevated, but under the same user as I am logged to the system. And I can't see the drive by `Get-PSDrive`

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of the `-Persist` switch is incorrect.  As noted in [the help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/New-PSDrive?view=powershell-5.1), make sure you're specifying global scope.

```
New-PSDrive -Name 'X' -PSProvider 'FileSystem' -Root '\\share\C$' -Scope 'Global' -Persist
```

---

> ```
> -Persist [<SwitchParameter>]
> ```
>
> Indicates that this cmdlet creates a Windows mapped network drive.
>   Mapped network drives are saved in Windows on the local computer. They
>   are persistent, not session-specific, and can be viewed and managed in
>   File Explorer and other tools.
>
> When you scope the command locally, that is, without dot-sourcing, the Persist parameter does not persist the creation of a
>   PSDrive beyond the scope in which you run the command. If you run
>   New-PSDrive inside a script, and you want the new drive to persist
>   indefinitely, you must dot-source the script. For best results, to
>   force a new drive to persist, specify Global as the value of the Scope
>   parameterin addition to adding Persist to your
>           command.
>
> The name of the drive must be a letter, such as D or E. The value of Root parameter must be a UNC path of a different computer. The
>   value of the PSProvider parameter must be FileSystem.
>
> To disconnect a Windows mapped network drive, use the Remove-PSDrive cmdlet. When you disconnect a Windows mapped network
>   drive, the mapping is permanently deleted from the computer, not just
>   deleted from the current session.
>
> Mapped network drives are specific to a user account. Mapped network drives that you create in sessions that are started by using
>   the Run as administrator option or by using the credential of another
>   user are not visible in a session that was started without explicit
>   credentials, or by using the credentials of the current user.

Comment: I believe I specified my question inprecisely. I'll modify it right away to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

For me the command

```
New-PSDrive -Name "X" -Root "\\some\path" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Persist
```

persisted the drive only until reboot. Running `net use` instead fixed this:

```
net use x: \\some\path /persistent:Yes
```

So these commands seem very much not equivalent. I am on some weird corporate VPN though so YMMV.